# What is the proper way to apply the login_form_bottom filter?

Tags: customization, filters, login

Here is my current code.

```
function custom_login_footer() {
    return '<p>text text text</p>';
}
add_filter('login_form_bottom', 'custom_login_footer');
```

I am trying to add text below the submit button, but I do not know how to apply the `login_form_bottom` filter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your code is correct, however, that filter only applies to the `wp_login_form()` function, which is not what `wp-login.php` uses, so you won't be seeing your text there if that's what you're expecting! try adding a call to `wp_login_form()` in a template to see what the filter does.

Comment: Thank you Milo. Although I did not achieve the result I wanted, you did answer the question. I'll open a new one to rephrase my question with this newly presented information.

Comment: For me, this also explains why `login_form_top` and `login_form_middle` are not called / "not working".